# Unexpected behavior from 2-level Task.ContinueWith

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have some code that lays out like this:

**Class1**

```
Task<List<ConfSession>> getSessionsTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var confSessions = 
                    TaskHelper<ConfSession>.InvokeTaskMagic(request);
                //PROBLEM - THIS CODE RACES TO THE NEXT LINE 
                //BEFORE confSessions IS POPULATED FROM THE LINE ABOVE - IE 
                //confSessions IS ALWAYS AN EMPTY LIST 
                //WHEN IT'S RETURNED
                return confSessions;
            }
        );
```

**Class2 (TaskHelper)**

```
//methods
public static List<T> InvokeTaskMagic(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    var resultList = new List<T>();

    Task<WebResponse> task1 = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
        (callback, o) => ((HttpWebRequest)o).BeginGetResponse(callback, o)
        , result => ((HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(result)
        , request);

    task1.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
    {
        if (antecedent.IsFaulted)
        {
            return;
        }

        WebResponse webResponse;
        try
        {
            webResponse = task1.Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex1)
        {
            throw ex1.InnerException;
        }

        string responseString;

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse)
        {
            using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        if (responseString != null)
        {
            resultList = 
               JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(responseString);
        }
    });

    return resultList;
}
```

TaskHelper is a class I created to standardize a bunch of redundant task code that I had in several methods. It exists only to take an HttpWebRequest, execute it in a Task, get the response in the ContinueWith block, parse the response into a `List<T>`, and return the `List<T>`.

I wrapped Class1's call to TaskHelper in a task because I need to get the result from the InvokeTaskMagic method before I continue in class1 (i.e. the next step in class1 is to use the `List<T>`. As it says in the comments in the code, my problem is that the Task in class1 returns an empty list every time because it's not waiting for the response from the InvokeTaskMagic method in the TaskHelper class.

Is this expected? Is there a way to make getSessionsTask wait to return until TaskHelper.InvokeTaskMagic returns?

UPDATE: 
The working code follows - thanks Servy for your help.

```
public static class TaskHelper<T> where T : class
{
    //methods
    public static Task<List<T>> InvokeTaskMagic(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        var resultList = new List<T>();

        Task<WebResponse> task1 = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
            (callback, o) => ((HttpWebRequest)o).BeginGetResponse(callback, o)
            , result => ((HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState).EndGetResponse(result)
            , request);

        return task1.ContinueWith<List<T>>((antecedent) =>
        {
            if (antecedent.IsFaulted)
            {
                return new List<T>();
            } 

            WebResponse webResponse;
            try
            {
                webResponse = task1.Result;
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex1)
            {
                throw ex1.InnerException;
            }

            string responseString;

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webResponse)
            {
                using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }

            if (responseString != null)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(responseString);
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<T>();
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

The InvokeTaskMagic method is called like this:

```
var getCommentsAboutTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                var comments = TaskHelper<Comment>.InvokeTaskMagic(request);
                return comments;
            });

        getCommentsAboutTask.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
            {
                if (antecedent.IsFaulted)
                { return; }

                var commentList = antecedent.Result.Result;
                UIThread.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    foreach (Comment c in commentList)
                    {
                        AllComments.Add(c);
                        GetCommentRelatedInfo(c);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. `Class2.method` points to `task2` method?

Comment: The question would be much clearer if you included actual code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Soner. I've updated the pseudo code. Svick, I know real code is nice, but the problem here is not syntax, it's design, so I feel that it's clearer to describe it with the pseudo code here to minimize the lines needed to communicate the problem.

Comment: You're right svick - as usual when someone suggests real code. I've added it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is this expected? Is there a way to make my class1.task1 continueblock wait for my class2.task2 continueblock?

Sure, just call `ContinueWith` on the second task's continuation instead of on the first task.

If you need it to wait until both are done you can use `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Servy, but how can you write a ContinueWith on another ContinueWith? And would it work when the two ContinueWith blocks are in different classes? I basically need Class1.Method1.Task1 to call Class2.Method2, which contains a Task that does an HttpWebRequest and gets the response in its ContinueWith block (ContinueWithBlock2), and then execute Task1.ContinueWith after Task2.ContinueWithBlock2 is complete. I've updated my post to clarify this.

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz Sure, you can chain the continuewiths as many times as you want.  ContinueWIth returns another task, and you can just continue on that.  Just have return the task that you want to add a continuation for from the other class and use that return value in the first method.

Comment: Thanks @servy - I've just updated my post to have real code. I like the simplicity of returning the `List<T>` from TaskHelper.InvokeTaskMagic - is it possible to keep this simplicity while getting everything to execute in the proper order, or is refactoring InvokeTaskMagic to return a Task the only way?

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz You should return a `Task<List<T>>` rather than a list that won't be populated until some indeterminate point in the future.  In fact, you code won't ever work.  At the end of your continuation you're not adding items to the list you're just assigning a new list to the variable, but the old list has already been returned, so the caller of the method will never see the items returned from the async operation.  If you return a `Task<List<T>>` that problem goes away.

Comment: This line confuses me: "At the end of your continuation you're not adding items to the list you're just assigning a new list to the variable" - I am adding items to the list. This code works if I don't try to split it into two classes.

Other than that, though, I understand your point. Thanks for helping me see the problem! I'll try to return a Task<List<T>> and post the results here.

Comment: No - I've got it. You're right, JsonConvert.DeserializeObjecte<List<T>>() reassigns a new value to the variable resultList. I understand what you're saying. The problem is a race condition between the Continuation and the return statement in the InvokeTaskMagic method - and the return statement always wins.

Comment: So what would this look like? I have a Task<WebResponse> in my method - how can I get to the point where I'm returning a Task<List<T>>?

Comment: @AndrewBSchultz First, change the return type of the method.  Second, return the result of the call to `ContinueWith`, since `ContinueWith` returns another task.  Inside of `ContinueWIth`, instead of assigning the list to a local variable, just `return` the `List<T>` inside of the lambda.  If you do that, the `ContinueWIth` call will return a `Task<List<T>>` that you can then return one level up.  The while thing will take *very* little to change.

Comment: Thanks Servy - that's it. I'll update my OP with the new code.

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar to your code some time ago and it is difficult getting it to work properly with error handling etc.

First I created a generic method to handles continuations with different return type

```
private AsyncCallback EndAsync<T1, T2>(TaskCompletionSource<T2> tcs,
                                       Func<IAsyncResult, T1> endMethod, 
                                       Func<T1, T2> continueWith) {
    return ar => {
        T1 result1;
        try {
            result1 = endMethod(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            tcs.SetException(err);
            return;
        }

        try {
            T2 result2 = continueWith(result1);
            tcs.SetResult(result2);
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            tcs.SetException(err);
            return;
        }
    };
}
```

Then I create the async task like this:

```
public Task<List<T>> GetDataAsync(IProxy proxy) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<List<T>>();
    var asyncCallback = EndAsync(tcs, 
                                 proxy.EndGetData, 
                                 result => result != null ? 
                                           ProcessResult(result) : 
                                           new List<T>());
    proxy.BeginGetData(asyncCallback);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```